# Помогите исправить ошибки в блок схеме

Tags: pascal, блок-схема

````
```   
program program2;
var a,b,c: integer;
begin
WriteLn('Программа для нахождения всех делителей чисел');
WriteLn('Введите от какого числа');
Readln(a);
WriteLn('Введите до какого числа');
REadln(b); 
while a<=b do begin
write (a,':');
for c := 2 to a-1 do begin
If a mod c = 0 then 
Write(c,' ');
end;
Writeln;
a := a+1;
end;
end.     
```
````

[image: блок-схема]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы проще было искать ошибки, понимать запрограммированный алгоритм код **ВСЕГДА** должен быть **ОТФОРМАТИРОВАН**!

```
program program2;

var
  a, b, c: integer;
begin
  writeln('Программа для нахождения всех делителей чисел');

  writeln('Введите от какого числа');
  readln(a);

  writeln('Введите до какого числа');
  readln(b);

  while a <= b do
  begin
    write(a, ':');

    for c := 2 to a - 1 do
      if a mod c = 0 then
        write(c, ' ');

    writeln;

    a := a + 1;
  end;
end.
```

После этого намного проще понять, что не так с блок схемой. Например, сразу видно, что `while` содержит не одну инструкцию как в блок схеме, а несколько, включая цикл. В цикле есть условие и т.д.

Успехов!